# GeoServer 2.4.1: How to use JSONP in a WFS request?

Tags: geoserver, wfs, json

I've read that I can enable JSONP by setting ENABLE_JSONP in web.xml:

```
  <context-param>
    <param-name>ENABLE_JSONP</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
  </context-param>
```

And I've read you can set outputFormat=json&format_options=callback:myCallback but I only get json back.  Is this functionality broken/reverted?  I'm on Windows 8.1.

Comment: Where's your wfs, we can test it. I have it working in GeoServer 2.4, so it must be somethign to do with your config. Did you restart Tomcat after changing the setting?

Answer (score 7):

I got it to work using Geoserver 2.3 and Leaflet with WFS 1.0.0 [here](http://ccb.capecodgis.com/).

When I changed to version 1.1.0 and 2.0.0 it returned the same json object as 1.0.0 but neither rendered on the map. Not sure why and it's a bit beyond me.

Here's what I'm using:

```
var rootUrl = 'http://tomcat.capecodgis.com/geoserver/capecodgis/ows';

var defaultParameters = {
    service: 'WFS',
    version: '1.0.0',
    request: 'GetFeature',
    typeName: 'capecodgis:monitor_station',
    maxFeatures: 200,
    outputFormat: 'text/javascript',
    format_options: 'callback: getJson'

};

var parameters = L.Util.extend(defaultParameters);

$.ajax({
    url: rootUrl + L.Util.getParamString(parameters),
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    jsonpCallback: 'getJson',
    success: handleJson
});

function handleJson(data) {
    L.geoJson(data, {
        onEachFeature: onEachFeature,
        pointToLayer: function (feature, latlng) {
            return L.circleMarker(latlng, geojsonMarkerOptions);
            //return L.marker(latlng);
        }
    }).addTo(map);
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: This works because get getCapabilities already indicates that text/javascript is supported:
http://tomcat.capecodgis.com/geoserver/capecodgis/ows?service=wfs&request=getCapabilities

Answer (score 2):

According to this [document](http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/services/wfs/outputformats.html) `outputFormat=json` is only included for backward compatibility and you should use `outputFormat=text/javascript` for a JSONP response.

Comment: Tried that but got a similar error:
Failed to find response for output format text/javascript

Comment: what version of geoserver and wfs are you using? What does the getCapabilities doc suggest are available outputs

Comment: GeoServer 2.4.1 and tried 2.0.0 and 1.1.0 with the same outcome:
http://127.0.0.1:8080/geoserver/ows?service=wfs&request=GetFeature&version=2.0.0&typeName=topp:states&propertyName=STATE_NAME,PERSONS&BBOX=-110.29075,22.72375,-81.41025,51.60425,EPSG:4326&maxFeatures=1&outputFormat=text/javascript&format_options=callback:foobar

Seems to be a known issue: https://jira.codehaus.org/browse/GEOS-5749

Comment: You can't give us a localhost URL. Pastebin the xml, or stick it somewhere.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the success function is not called with the JSONP call. You need to change the AJAX call accordingly. You need to set jsonp:'format_options' on the AJAX call. The callback is then in the jsonpCallback parameter.

```
    $.ajax('http://demo.opengeo.org/geoserver/wfs',{
        type: 'GET',
        data: {
            service: 'WFS',
            version: '1.1.0',
            request: 'GetFeature',
            typename: 'osm:water_areas',
            srsname: 'EPSG:3857',
            outputFormat: 'text/javascript',
            bbox: extent.join(',') + ',EPSG:3857'
            },
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        jsonpCallback:'callback:loadFeatures',
        jsonp:'format_options'
        });
    }
```

Comment: Unfortunately, no.  I'm having the same problem. Using _that_ example works; but using _my_ geoserver tells me it doesn't accept `text/javascript`, despite enabling it in web.xml