# How to add Geoserver WFS to Leaflet JS Application

Tags: postgis, geoserver, leaflet, wfs

I have a PostGIS database and have successfully consumed a table into GeoServer and published a WFS.  Are there REST endpoints available for these WFS' akin to ESRI's feature services?  How are parameters to be constructed?

Comment: have you looked at [this post](http://www.gaiaresources.com.au/json-with-geoserver-and-leaflet/)? "Leaflet doesn't directly support WFS services on their own, but it will happily work with JSON data, fortunately GeoServer can output a WFS service as JSON"

Answer (score 13):

To learn more about the Rest-Module of geoserver i can recommend you this website:
http://geoserver.geo-solutions.it/edu/en/rest/using_rest.html
but I guess that you just want to load a WFS-Layer into your Leaflet-map, so you can have a look at this post:

http://blog.georepublic.info/2012/leaflet-example-with-wfs-t/
Here the Requests for the WFS-layer are written from scatch. I have tested it and it works.

Or this Leaflet-Plugin:
https://github.com/flatrockgeo/leaflet.wfs-t

If you don't need WFS-T than on of these posts could be enough:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25187937/loading-geojson-layers-from-geoserver-to-leaflet-map-based-on-the-current-boundi  (answer of user "user3919282")

or this post where it is explained how to enable jsonp in Geoserver:
[Getting WFS data from Geoserver into leaflet](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/64406/getting-wfs-data-from-geoserver-into-leaflet)

I have tested this post (Answer from user "geomajor56")
[GeoServer 2.4.1: How to use JSONP in a WFS request?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/76638/geoserver-2-4-1-how-to-use-jsonp-in-a-wfs-request)
and made a JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/expedio/8r1ncv6a/

Comment: I can't seem to get your fiddle to work, L is not defined and then map container is not defined

Comment: Thanks, this helped, but the answer is kinda useless if all these URLs suddenly stop working.

Answer (score 7):

We have implemented WFST plugin here: https://github.com/Flexberry/Leaflet-WFST
It supports reading GML and GeoJSON data, and can send transaction requests (insert, update, delete).