# Using Google Maps API v2 and Maps engine?

Tags: google-maps-api, google-maps-engine

I am researching on the options in drawing shapes on Google Maps with API v2 and Google Maps Engine. I have managed to set up the admission to draw a viewed layer on my setup on my site.

Does anyone know if it is possible to access your own layers and maps and draw an save the tables with attributes and so on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would not use Google API v2, as it is deprecated: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/v2/v2tov3
For version 3 see https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/shapes
Google maps engine will also be deprecated soon: http://www.appgeo.com/blog/life-google-maps-engine-positive-disruption/

Saving your data could always be done with something like php if there don't exist examples doing that yet.
Is there any particular reason why you don't want to use OpenLayers or Leaflet instead?

Comment: Thanks for reply. It has to work properly on either iOS or Android and needs to center position from GPS. I've been working only a little with Leaflet. Can it do the trick? I need to select the desired attribute in my table as well. And last I need sattelitephotos as view. It's for field study to help me with orientation.

Comment: yes sure, for example saving edits can be done with wfs-T ( https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/129965/how-to-add-geoserver-wfs-to-leaflet-js-application/130553#130553 ) or if you are more into NoSQL with pouchDB/CouchDB  https://github.com/calvinmetcalf/leaflet.pouch