# How to load GeoJSON from GeoServer to define a variable in Leaflet?

Tags: geoserver, leaflet, geojson, wfs

How can I load a GeoJSON file from GeoServer in Leaflet? There are lots of suggestions out there, but none of them work for me.

Currently my app loads a js file from the server that starts like this:

```
var boundaries ={ - followed by the geojson file content
```

To speed things up (and make it work in older browsers) how do I define variable boundaries = { - GeoJSON from GeoServer?

All I have so far is (not working):

```
var owsrootUrl = 'http://185.19.29.22:8080/geoserver/cresh/ows';

var defaultParameters = {
    service : 'WFS',
    version : '1.0.0',
    request : 'GetFeature',
    typeName : 'cresh:datazone_popup',
    outputFormat : 'json',
    format_options : 'callback:getJson',
    SrsName : 'EPSG:4326'
};

var parameters = L.Util.extend(defaultParameters);
var URL = owsrootUrl + L.Util.getParamString(parameters);

var boundaries = null;
var ajax = $.ajax({
    url : URL,
    dataType : 'json',
    jsonpCallback : 'getJson',
    success : function (response) {
        boundaries = L.geoJson(response, {
            style: function (feature) {
                return {
                    stroke: false,
                    fillColor: 'FFFFFF',
                    fillOpacity: 0
                };
                }
        });
    }
});
```

Geoserver is installed on the same server as my webapp and WFS is running.

Answer (score 1):

Hi your url should be : 
/`geoserver/workspaceName/wfs?request=GetFeature&version=1.0.0&typeName=storeName:layerName&outputFormat=json`

Keep the default style for now, 
If this doesn't work you should see an error message in your console, which will help you out!

Comment: Changed the URL to '/geoserver/cresh/ows?service=WFS&version=1.0.0&request=GetFeature&typeName=cresh:datazone_popup&maxFeatures=50&outputFormat=application%2Fjson', no errors, but also not working as variable in function yet..

Answer (score 1):

Here is a working jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/expedio/8r1ncv6a/ I posted while answering following question:

[How to add Geoserver WFS to Leaflet JS Application](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/129965/how-to-add-geoserver-wfs-to-leaflet-js-application/130553#130553)

To test if your geoserver is supporting jsonp yet just have a look at the preview section of your GeoServer installation.

Answer (score 0):

In your geoserver directory locate the web.xml file (should be here: geoserver\WEB-INF) and add the following just above `</web-app>` at the end:

```
<context-param>
        <param-name>ENABLE_JSONP</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>
```

and here is a working example:

```
var owsrootUrl = 'http://myip:8080/geoserver/opengeo/ows';

//---------------------------------------------------------------------
var defaultParameters2 = {
    service : 'WFS',
    version : '2.0',
    request : 'GetFeature',
    typeName : 'opengeo:csg_ukpn',
    outputFormat : 'text/javascript',
    format_options : 'callback:getJson',
    SrsName : 'EPSG:4326'
};


      var geoJsonLayer = new L.GeoJSON();

      function getJson(data) {
          geoJsonLayer.addData(data);
      }


var parameters2 = L.Util.extend(defaultParameters2);
var URL2 = owsrootUrl + L.Util.getParamString(parameters2);

var markers = L.markerClusterGroup();
var WFSLayer2 = null;
var ajax2 = $.ajax({
    url : URL2,
    dataType : 'jsonp',
    jsonpCallback : 'getJson',
    success : function (response) {
       WFSLayer2 = L.geoJson(response, {
            pointToLayer: function(feature, latlng) {
               var smallIcon2 = L.icon({
                                  iconSize: [27, 27],
                                  iconAnchor: [13, 27],
                                  popupAnchor:  [1, -24],
                                  iconUrl: 'leaflet/icons/' + feature.properties.csg_survey_status + '.png'
               });

               return L.marker(latlng, {icon: smallIcon2});
},
            onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {
                popupOptions = {maxWidth: 600, maxHeight: 300};

                layer.bindLabel('<h4>'+feature.properties.plant_no+'</h4>');
                layer.bindPopup(feature.properties.plant_no+'<br>'+feature.properties.csg_survey_pack+'<br>'+feature.properties.csg_street_view
                    ,popupOptions);
            }
        }).addTo(markers.addTo(map));
    }
});
```

In your javascript just replace the datatype to jsonp. `dataType : 'jsonp',`

Comment: Hi, thanks! I have enabled 'jsonp' and it looks like it's loading, I just don't get the javascript function going (see comments below), sorry I'm really new.

Comment: Sorry I missed one step: restart geoserver

Comment: outputFormat : 'text/javascript',

Comment: Use your code above, but replace the datatype to jsonp, and the outputFormat should be text/javascript