# How to use GeoJSON from Geoserver in Leaflet?

Tags: postgis, geoserver, leaflet, geojson

Is it possible to consume the GeoJSON from Geoserver as a 'dynamic' service in a Leaflet application?

So far I have only seen how to consume a static GeoJSON file.

Being able to construct GeoJSON from what GeoServer publishes means we can publish PostGIS data to a Leaflet app without having to re-build a GeoJSON file.

The URL from GeoServer looks like this:

http://servername:8080/geoserver/dps/ows?service=WFS&version=1.0.0&request=GetFeature&typeName=dps:Schools_Current&maxFeatures=50&outputFormat=application%2Fjson

...and the GeoJSON itself looks like this (for a single feature):

```
{"type":"FeatureCollection","totalFeatures":221,"features":[{"type":"Feature","id":"Schools_Current.521","geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[-105.02726842,39.66184512]},"geometry_name":"geom","properties":{"school_name":"DSST: College View High School","abbreviation":"DSST:CV HS  ","elem":0,"mid":0,"high":1,"schnum":521,"classification":"Charter                  ","school_level":"High                     ","current_config":"9-10      ","final_config":"9-12      ","b_elem":0,"b_mid":0,"b_high":0,"label_x":-105.025346737628,"label_y":39.6620286090456}
```

Comment: Just have a look at my answer to another question: http://gis.stackexchange.com/a/130553/45041 and the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/expedio/8r1ncv6a/ . Does this work for you, too?

Comment: @ThomasB there is some logic in one of those answers that looks promising... I'll test on Monday!

Comment: @ThomasB I was able to reproduce your jsfiddle example, and all looks straightforward enough, but getting a really weird error in console: "SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<'[Learn More]  ows:1" --- no idea what that means?~!?! But maybe this is due to a cross origin policy error...?

Comment: @ThomasB ahhh got it to work... great solution in your JSFiddle... did you want to add the JSFIddle example to your other answer? That was the solution to this question... thank you again!!!

Comment: @ThomasB have you ever worked with CQL filters with your method above? I can set the CQL filter but not sure how to update it...

Comment: @AndreSilva sorry - what do you mean?

Comment: You commented that ThomasB's fiddle solved your question. Hence, add it as answer, so this Q can be marked answered and also future readers can benefit from finding an answer without having to mine information from comments. An answer would also protect your Q from being closed (as changes to asker's circumstances have rendered it obsolete), and eventually deleted (despite it is positively scored, which difficulties the latter). I will upvote your Q/A if you do it. Tks.

Comment: @AndreSilva thanks for the reminder - I had forgotten to figure out how to post the solution given how I ended up using it. But i'll dig around this week.